# CakePHP Datatype Associations

Tags: cakephp

I'm playing around with CakePHP. I noticed when I select a different field type in my database for example "datetime", "varchar" or "tinyint" cake automatically interprets the field for example:

```
varchar = text
tinyint = checkbox
datetime = date select field
```

Is there any source where I can find a list of field types used for which datatype in my database? I've googled several times but can't seem to find the right description.

What also bothers me - is there a simplified field to create an upload field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That task is made by the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements). As for uploads, there's the [file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3afile) method. *(Not sure if you already know it and are looking for alternatives.)*

Comment: Thats exactly what i've been looking for. Thank you :)